# Mysql Best way to store an arbitrary number of value in a table

Tags: mysql, database

I am wondering what would be the best approach to store, for let's say `languages` in a `user` table when the user can have as many langauge as he wishes, and hopefully without using serialized data as this field will be searched intensivly.

I was thinking limtating the number of entries, for exemple maximun 4 language and in the user table have lang1, lang2 ..

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Specifically you need to map a ["Many to Many" association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

You need 3 tables.

```
User(id, name)
Language (id, language_name)
User_Language(id,id_user,id_language)
```

To get all the language for a user id 3:

```
SELECT l.language_name
FROM User u
JOIN user_language ul ON (u.id=ul.id_user)
JOIN  Language l ON (l.id = ul.id_language)
WHERE u.id = 3
```

**EDIT:**

Two things are important to notice @silkAdmin. The first one, as @BryceAtNetwork23 noted, there's no need to put an id on the User_Language table. The second is that, you should learn about [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), specially [MySQL Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (becouse the SQL tends to differ in different DB engines). After you dig a little bit more you will be able to see that joining the User table in the previous query is also not needed, that could be simplified as:

```
SELECT l.language_name
FROM user_language ul
JOIN  Language l ON (l.id = ul.id_language)
WHERE ul.user_id = 3
```

But I added it in the first answer to make things easier to you.

**Why using the Language table**

My answer just reflects the way I'd do it. There are plenty of ways to acomplish what've asked for. Said that, i explain myself.

Let's think in extremes. The first extreme is to store the languages in the user table, as you said above. For example, we can have a column and separate the values with a semicolon. Something like this

```
User: (1, "John", "spanish;english;japanese")
```

The advantage of that is that you won't need any join. Given the id of your user you can get the languages. The disadvantages is that it will be really painful to search on that. How you get all your users with language "Spanish"? (The bottom line here is that you can't index your data). Another disadvantage, that is kind of old now, is the overuse of disk space. In the time when the DBs and Normalization was invented, disk space was really costly. So, storing this:

```
User: (1, "John", "spanish;english;japanese") 
User: (2, "Mary", "spanish;english")
```

That was somthing that couldn't be tolerated. So, some guy came and say: "Hey, let's use ids, so, we can turn it into":

```
User: (1, "John", "1;2;3") 
User: (2, "Mary", "1;2")

Language (1,"spanish")
Language (2,"english")
```

For 10.000 users and just a few hundred of languages, that's a huge improvement on disk usage (maybe in our time, this is not true anymore, and i'll come to that later). That solved the disk problem, but we still has the search problem. Again, How you get all your users with language "Spanish"? Well, with this design, you should iterate over the users table and get the language column, split it between ";" and look for the id 1.

That's why we started using the approach I showed you before.

So, so far so good. Pretty good explanation ;)

**Big disclaimer**

As I said before, there are several ways to do this. It depends on your case and what do you want to achive. If you want to search in terms of that column (give me users that speak english, for example) you should consider the design i told you at the top of my answer.

Right now there are a "new wave" of data solutions that are called no-sql databases (it varies) that try to denormalize data. If you're concerned about the over-normalization of your schemas, you should take a look at that. I recommend you MongoDB and CouchDB, becouse those are the easier to start with.

**About joins**

Don't worry about the performance of 2 joins. If you've performance issues it's not for this. DB engines are created with this purpose. With a good memory cache and index optimization it should work smoothly.

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't need an ID field on USER_LANGUAGE.  The fields id_user and id_language (together as a concatenated key) would ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a good practice. I don't need the user table in that join neither, but for the sake of the explanation i added it.

Comment: @santiagobasulto Thanks for the detailed answer. I know how to use joins but by keeping performance in mind i try to use them only when there are no other way. Though i am curious why using a language table ? Shouldn t the user language table be enough (replacing id_language by a enum field)

Comment: @antiagobasulto It does, thanks a lot i'd +1 it again if i could

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best way is to use an additional table with columns `lang_id` and `user_id`. There you can store any number of user/language associations (one per row).

Answer (score 1):

Create table user_languages

```
 user_id int,
 language_id int,
```

with constraints:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id, language_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES language(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

With such constraints, users can have assigned as many languages as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this, is to have a USER table, a USER_LANGUAGES table and a LANGUAGES table.  This way, a user can have as many languages as they want.

```
USER
user_id int
user_name varchar

USER_LANGUAGES
user_id int
lang_id int

LANGUAGES
lang_id int
lang_name varchar
```

USER stores the user-based fields.  LANGUAGES stores data on each specific langauge (English, German, etc...).  USER_LANGUAGES stores the association of which users know which language(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider having two tables. One with `users` and one with `languages`. It is easier to maintain and it is easier to do `joins` to these tables.